# how to finish modal animation in react-native-modal componentwillunmount?

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal, react-component-unmount

I am looking for a solution to delay RN component unmount until `react-native-modal` `animationOut` is completed. This animation is triggered by setting `isVisible=false`.
With my current implementation the animation performs as expected on `componentWillMount` hook, however the problem is in `componentWillUnmount` the alert unmounts without an animation. I suspect this is because the component unmounts before the animation even has a change to start.
Here's the alert component:

```
//modal component
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

export default CustomAlert = props => {

    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsVisible(true)
        return () => setIsVisible(false);
    }, [])

    return (
        <Modal
            isVisible={isVisible}
            animationIn={'slideInUp'}
            animationOut={'slideOutDown'}
        >
            <View
               ...
            </View>
        </Modal>
    )
};
```

Here's how the custom alert needs to be used:

```
export default ApplicationScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

    ...
    const doSomething = () => {
        ...
        //show alert
        setAlert({ title: 'title', message: 'message'});
        ...
        //hide alert
        setAlert(null);
        ...
    }
    ...

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

            {alert &&
                <CustomAlert
                    title={alert?.title}
                    message={alert?.message}
                    ...
                />
            }
            ...
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are containing the `CustomAlert` in a conditional rendering. Once the alert is set to false, the Modal would dismount directly.
You could pass the `alert` state into `CustomAlert` as property and then into `Modal`. The 's property `isVisible` would hanlde the render of the modal for you with animation.

ApplicationScreen:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <CustomAlert
    title={alert?.title}
    message={alert?.message}
    isAlertVisible={alert? true : false}
  />
</SafeAreaView>
```

in CustomAlert:

```
return (
        <Modal
            isVisible={props.isAlertVisible}
            animationIn={'slideInUp'}
            animationOut={'slideOutDown'}
        >
            <View
               ...
            </View>
        </Modal>
    )
```